# How to access and use skeleton joint coordinates using OpenNI, ASUS Xtion, and ROS?

Tags: tracking, detection, ros, openni, asus-xtion

To develop a person follower robot, I am using ASUS Xtion and OpenNI. To obtain both RGB image and skeleton joints, I am using a skeleton tracker script (https://github.com/Chaos84/skeleton_tracker). Tracker publishes joints in "/tf" 
But the thing is that I cannot use those joint coordinates in my script. I don't know how to access them. How can I access and use them in my script to make the robot move according to those coordinates?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To get joint coordinates and angles from a /tf topic, you need to right a tf listener which is explained in this [link](http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20tf%20listener%20(C%2B%2B)).

Also you can look at one of my ROS packages where I wrote tf listener using OpenNI and ASUS Xtion. Here is the [link](https://github.com/tkelestemur/fall_risk_assesment/blob/master/human_motion_analysis/activity_tracker/src/activity_tracker.cpp).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In fact, I had looked before I posted but the names of the signals were different than the document that they are explained. After I have found the right names for them, I could accomplish it by using the method in the link that you give. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use another skeleton detection/tracker, the BodySkeletonTracker:

https://github.com/derzu/BodySkeletonTracker

Look how does it works:

[image: IMAGE ALT TEXT HERE]

You can get the joints points getting an object of the class SkeletonPoints.